# Rearrange php array to javascript array problem

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a group of PHP array data like this:

```
$xx_add = array(
    array('id'=>1, 'name'=>"jiahui shop", 'description' => "Jl. Sukarjo Wiryopranoto No. 69 A, Pasar Baru", 'lat'=>-6.249650, 'lng'=>106.850288),
    array('id'=>2, 'name'=>"Success United Pte Ltd", 'description' =>"Atrium Plaza Blok E Unit 122 5 Jl. Senen Raya No. 135 Senen, Jakarta Pusat", 'lat'=>-6.167170, 'lng'=>106.873894),
    array('id'=>3, 'name'=>"Chilis Restaurant, Lt. 2, Jl. MH. Thamrin No. 11, Sarinah", 'description' =>"Sarinah Building, Lt. 2, Jl. MH. Thamrin No. 11, Sarinah", 'lat'=>-6.197090, 'lng'=>106.738213)
);
```

How can I do, so that I can get a bundle of javascript array as like shown below?

```
var $xx_add = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'jiahui shop', 'description': 'Jl. Sukarjo Wiryopranoto No. 69 A, Pasar Baru', 'lat': -6.249650, 'lng': 106.850288 }, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Success United Pte Ltd', 'description': 'Atrium Plaza Blok E Unit 122 5 Jl. Senen Raya No. 135 Senen, Jakarta Pusat', 'lat': -6.167170, 'lng': 106.873894 }, 
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Chilis Restaurant', 'description': 'Sarinah Building, Lt. 2, Jl. MH. Thamrin No. 11, Sarinah', 'lat': -6.197090, 'lng': 106.738213 }
];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also embed PHP in your JavaScript block (which is the most ugly solution I can think of):

```
<?php
    $xx_add = array(...);
?>

<script>
    var xx_add = <?php json_encode($xx_add); ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get JSON code from PHP? Use `json_encode()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Then you'll need to add the variable declaration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to JSON:

```
json_encode($xx_add);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

I use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

[JSON encode it](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo "var xx_add = jQuery.jsonParse('".json_encode($xx_add).'");";
```